# How to disable navigation bar back button when some activity is loading in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have two ViewControllers.

In second view controller, When I click on search button action (activity started, like web service is executing).After getting data from web service, It will show UIAlertview.

My problem is, When I pressed search button(activity start), now I clicked on back button on Navigation Bar. Now, I am on previous view(First view controller). I have now response of search button activity with UIAlertview.

Obviously, My app will crash on OK button of alert view.

So, In that case

**How can I disable navigation bar back button? (when I click on search)**

OR

**How to prevent UIAlerview to display when I click on back button?**

Update :

I tried all methods to hide back bar button. :-)

Comment: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;  ?

Comment: the best way to solve this is to disable user interaction of view.

Comment: I've tried all method to hide back button. See update :-)

Comment: @MayankJain I've tried on button click to disable user interaction too.

Comment: write this code in your search button's action:- 
    self.navigationController.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
After getting data:- self.navigationController.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: did you try this [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];  ???

Comment: self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

Comment: save reference of your UIAlertView as property

Comment: Try `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;`

Comment: Bring activity to front of the window and disable all other views. And as the response get stop the activity and enable the background views.

Answer (score 1):

Only hiding button or disabling user interaction is not the best practice cause the user won't know what's happening with the app, in case of longer process the user will thing that the app is frozen and will terminate it. Good practice in these cases are HUDs, progress indicators that block user interactions. In this case the user will see that something is happening in background and will wait for it to finish, and if he tires to go back the HUD wont let him. I usually use this one:
https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD
, the implementation is very easy and it looks quite nice, but you can always program one of your own.

Comment: I am also using MBProgressHUD. Navigation back button working while HUD animating or processing. You can disable interaction of other controls like buttons,label but not navigation bar. :-)

Comment: It should block the entire screen, it does in my case, when HUD is shown i can't touch back...

Answer (score 0):

save reference of your UIAlertView as property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertView *alert;
```

show alert

```
  self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [self.alert show];
```

in case of "risk", remove the delegate

```
self.alert.delegate = nil;
```

When risk finished, reset delegate

```
self.alert.delegate = self;
```